# Increment Counter in Section Title

Tags: counters, section-titles

I wonder why I can not call `\stepcounter` within a section title.

For example, this code works fine:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcounter{mycounter}
\begin{document}
\section{Title \themycounter}
\stepcounter{mycounter}
\end{document}
```

But this code encounter attached error:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcounter{mycounter}
\begin{document}
\section{Title \themycounter \stepcounter{mycounter}}
\end{document}
```

Error:

```
The control sequence marked <to be read again> should
not appear between \csname and \endcsname.

d:/D-Repos/tmp/counter.tex:7: Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \MessageBreak 
l.7 ...itle \themycounter \stepcounter{mycounter}}
```

Comment: fragile command in a moving argument, you could `\protect` it but are you sure you want to do this? do you want the counter to increment again in the table of contents? Why not use the in built section counter?

Comment: I was not familiar with the fragile command that's why I asked this question. I also could not use the built-in section counter because I only want some sections to be numbered. @DavidCarlisle

Comment: use `\section` for numbered sections and `\section*`  for unnumbered ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should either run `\stepcounter{mycounter}` *before* `\section` or -- if it occurs in the argument of `\section` -- "protect" the `\stepcounter` directive via a `\protect` directive. (@DavidCarlisle has already mentioned the second alternative in a comment.)

*Addendum* (see also David Carlisle's comment below): If your document contains a `\tableofcontents` directive, you should *not* use the second method, as otherwise the numbering will be messed up.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcounter{mycounter}
\renewcommand\themycounter{\Alph{mycounter}}

\begin{document}
\stepcounter{mycounter}\section{Title \themycounter}

\section{\protect\stepcounter{mycounter}Title \themycounter}
\end{document}
```

Comment: but `\tableofcontents` will then change the numbering

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - Thanks for this comment. I've provided an addendum to mention the issue you raise prominently.